# OS X Firefox lockPref configuration error

Tags: macos, firefox, configuration

I am having issues getting lockPref working on my Mac. I have followed instructions [here](http://kb.mozillazine.org/Locking_preferences), as well as looking in other places for solutions. I have created a mozilla.cfg file, as well as a local-settings.js file in /Applications/Firefox/Contents/Resources/defaults/pref, as follows:

mozilla.cfg

```
//
lockPref("extensions.shownSelectionUI", true);
lockPref("extensions.autoDisableScopes", 11);
```

local-settings.js

```
pref("general.config.obscure_value", 0);
pref("general.config.filename", "mozilla.cfg");
```

These are both saved using Windows Latin encoding (have tried Windows Roman too). When opening Firefox, I am getting an error dialogue saying, "Failed to read the configuration file. Please contact your system administrator". I'm not sure where to go from here, as other solutions have involved UTF encoding problems and incorrect configuration values - I saved an empty mozilla.cfg file to attempt to rule that out, and the problem still persists.

FYI I'm using OS X 10.11.5 and Firefox 42.0. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, I didn't have mozilla.cfg in the correct location - I was storing it in the prefs folder with the local-settings.js, which is incorrect.

File locations are now as follows:

/Applications/Firefox.app/Contents/Resources/mozilla.cfg
/Applications/Firefox.app/Contents/Resources/defaults/pref/local-settings.js